# How can I solve this limit?(From AMM)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, factorial

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n-y^n}{e^x-e^y} \ dy \ dx -2n \right)$$

I cannot solve this question by myself anymore. I want to know how to solve this limit.

Comment: A flagger thinks this is a current problem. Not sure this would make it a (prohibited) contest problem, most likely it would... So, give a link to the source, please.

Comment: It's problem 12011 from the December 2017 issue. The deadline for solutions is 30 April 2018.

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown. Locking.